# How to keep underlay element hover when upper element pass through

Tags: javascript, css, animation, overlay

i have a situation when some div i hover on calls tooltip. And I have re-positioning logic in case tooltip does not fit the screen. But i faced a problem (epecially in FireFox) that when tooltip travels over "caller" div, "caller" div looses its hover state. This is 100% reproducible in FF, in Chrome works on some machines and on some does not.

Is there any solution for this?
I have creatted jsfiddle to show this. You will see that animation gets canceled - and yes i can do some workaround in such a simple case but reall situation is much more complex.

```
jsfiddle.net/5c1fdw6o/9/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may apply CSS: `pointer-events: none;` to the top layer, for that.

In your case:

```
.sliding-tooltip {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it hellped

Comment: No problem. Consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue so it may help other people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend switching html divs so the span would be above the other div.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="sliding-tooltip">
    I slide to the right
  </div>
  <span class="hover-item">Hover me!</span>
</div>
```

If this isn't enough you could use z-index on both elements to make sure div is always on top of the other. But make sure to position the span as relative.

```
.hover-item {
  color: blue;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```